# How to set up JMS in Glassfish Administration Console

Tags: glassfish, jms

I'm trying to set up the Connection Factory and the Queue for JMS through the GlassFish administration console, but I can't the that option in the list!

Any clue? I'm probably missing something, I'm quite new to GF.
[image: You can see (not see it, actually) it here!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to set up the glassfish xml, and then you can review the results in the console.  First, make sure you have your resource adapter deployed under applications.  For ActiveMQ, that would be activemq rar that you can find on their website.

Take a look at my question here which has everything you need:
[Need clarification on JMS vs ActiveMQ bean/resource configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212533/need-clarification-on-jms-vs-activemq-bean-resource-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't installed jms add-on.

At Admin console page under ***"Update Center"*** tabs click ***"Available Add-Ons"*** check ***"glassfish-jms"*** and ***"glassfish-jms-l10n"*** options and click ***"install"***.
Restart your glassfish server. ***"JMS Resources"*** will appear.